# Prove this endomorphism cannot have real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$f$ is an endomorphism of an $\Bbb R$-vector space $E$ with dimension $n\geq1$. $f$ satisfies $f^2+f+$Id$_E = 0$.

How can I go about showing that $f$ can't have real eigenvalues?

Comment: How do eigenvalues of $f$ and of $p(f)$ relate, when $p(x)$ is a polynomial?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x$ is an eigenvector of $f$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then evaluating your equation at $x$ gives $f(f(x))+f(x)+id(x)=0$, but since $x$ is an eigenvector $f(x)=\lambda x$ and $f(f(x))=f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)=\lambda^2 x$ where we used the linearity of $f$, so inserting into the first equation yields $$\lambda^2 x+\lambda x+x=0$$ which by the vector space axioms of scalar multiplication is equivalent to $$(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)x=0$$ Now since all eigenvector are assumed nonzero we have that $$\lambda^2+\lambda+1=0$$
But this equation has no real solutions so our linear map cannot have real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The minimal polynomial $q(x)$ of $f$ is the smallest anulator polynomial in the sense that if $p(f)=0$ then $q(x)\mid p(x)$. Moreover, $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $f$  if and only if $q(\lambda )=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $f$ with $f(x) = \lambda x$.

Then $0 = 0(x) = (f^2+f+id)(x) =f^2(x) + f(x) + x = \lambda^2 x + \lambda x + x = (\lambda^2+\lambda + 1)x$.

If $x\ne 0$, then $\lambda^2+\lambda+x=0$. But this polynomial has negative discriminant $D=1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot 1 = -3$ and so no real-valued solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any eigenvalue $\lambda$ would have to satisfy $\lambda^2+\lambda+1=0\implies \lambda=(1\pm\sqrt3i)/2$.